# Error: Type contract pSDATokenSale is not implicitly convertible to expected type contract pSDA

Tags: javascript, token, solidity, truffle

Type contract pSDATokenSale is not implicitly convertible to expected type contract pSDA.

I am getting the error above ^^ at the line with **`tokenContract = _tokenContract;`**. Any suggestions as to why this is happening and how to fix it?

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.12;

import "./pSDAToken.sol";


contract pSDATokenSale {
    address admin;
    pSDA public tokenContract;
    uint256 public tokenPrice;
    uint256 public tokensSold;

    event Sell(address _buyer, uint256 _amount);

    function pSDAToken(pSDATokenSale _tokenContract, uint256 _tokenPrice)
        public
    {
        admin = msg.sender;
        tokenContract = _tokenContract;
        tokenPrice = _tokenPrice;
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ehy
you wrote wrong the type of `_tokenContract` inside the function `pSDAToken()`

you wrote `_tokenContract` with type `pSDATokenSale`, and want to save it inside `tokenContract` that is `pSDA` type

this is the correct code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.12;

import "./pSDAToken.sol";


contract pSDATokenSale {
    address admin;
    pSDA public tokenContract;
    uint256 public tokenPrice;
    uint256 public tokensSold;

    event Sell(address _buyer, uint256 _amount);

    function pSDAToken(pSDA _tokenContract, uint256 _tokenPrice)
        public
    {
        admin = msg.sender;
        tokenContract = _tokenContract;
        tokenPrice = _tokenPrice;
    }
```